# Mysql - Avoid Cross Join to not get multiple duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, join, cross-join

I have two tables that I would like to get results from without cross-joining to get duplicate data.

**Table 1:** booksCheckedOut

```
row    |   userID   |      book    |  date
-------------------------------------------------
1      |    3       |      book1   |  Jan-26
2      |    3       |      book2   |  Jan-27
3      |    3       |      book3   |  Jan-28
4      |    3       |      book4   |  Jan-29
```

Table2: numberOfPagesRead

```
row     |    userID   |     name        |   date       |   pagesRead
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       |    3        |     John        |   Jan-26     |   4
2       |    3        |     John        |   Jan-27     |   7
3       |    3        |     John        |   Jan-28     |   8
```

I'm doing a sql query that looks like this:

```
select booksCheckedOut.book, numberOfPagesRead.pagesRead

from booksCheckedOut, numberOfPagesRead

where booksCheckedOut.userID='3' and numberOfPagesRead.userID='3'
```

**But I get results that look like this:** The rows are being multiplied (4 x 3 = 12 results)

```
book       |  pagesRead |     
-------------------------
book1      |    4       |      
book1      |    7       |     
book1      |    8       |     
book2      |    4       |
book2      |    7       |  
book2      |    8       |  
book3      |    4       |
book3      |    7       |   
book3      |    8       |   
book4      |    4       |   
book4      |    7       |   
book4      |    8       |
```

**This is what I want:**

```
book       |  pagesRead |     
-------------------------
book1      |    4       |      
book2      |    7       |     
book3      |    8       |     
book4      |            |
```

How do I prevent results from getting multiplied (cross joined)?

I know it makes no sense, butI don't want to associate the number of pages read to a particular book, it's just the way the current database is already set up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there is no relation, what are you going to display? Your output doesn't match even by date. 8 pages were read on Jan-29, while in your output you put the 8 next to the book that was read on Jan-28. And if date *is* the key, does that mean that you can't read more than one book per day? Without proper relations and a proper definition you might find a query that outputs that particular table, but it won't make sense.

Comment: I agree with Golez here, I can't see any way that this is possible given the current table design. Where do you get the idea that the user read 4 pages on book 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear the `UserId` and `date` are the keys joining these tables:

```
select co.book, nopr.pagesRead
from booksCheckedOut co join
     numberOfPagesRead nopr
     on co.userId = nopr.UserId and co.date = nopr.date
where co.userID = '3';
```

You should learn proper `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.

I added table aliases; the make queries easier to write and to read.